# is there a declarative way to set a jqGrid label's css class?

Tags: javascript, css, jqgrid

One can set the class(es) for the data cell using the colModel for the column, is there a similar way to declare additional classes for the the corresponding TH/label? I can see that there is a programmatic way using setLabel, but I'd want it in the declaration, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that jqGrid create column headers having ids which are constructed from the grid id and the column name property. For example if the grid has id='list' and you want set some styles for the column with the name 'name' (`name: 'name'`) you can define CSS styles forid='list_name'.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithHeaderStyles.htm) looks like

[image]

and uses the following CSS styles

```
<style type="text/css">
    #list_name {
        text-align: left;
        font-style: italic;
        color: red
    }
    #list_closed {
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    #list_note {
        text-align: left
    }
    #list_amount, #list_tax, #list_total {
        text-align: right;
        margin-right: 20px
    }
</style>
```

Comment: thanks, Oleg! That's pretty much what I did. I would have liked the ability to do it in the colDef, so the values can be run-time computed. (I know I can also hack that w/CSS...)

Comment: I meant colModel -the column model object array. Sorry.

Comment: @Jake: OK, I understand now what you mean, but [colModel](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options) don't support options which you need.